# What Join is it called and how to do it in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Please have a look at these Tables below. I've three tables where Invoice and Receipt tables don't have any direct link. They can only be linked using another Table and here it is "Invoice * Receipt Link Table"

Invoice Table

| **Invoice No** |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Receipt Table

| **Receipt No** |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Invoice * Receipt Link Table

| **Invoice No** | **Receipt No** |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |

Result table I'm expecting

| **Invoice No** | **Receipt No** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 |
| null | 2 |

What kind of join do we even call it and how to make a join among these three tables to get result as in the 4th table?

Comment: Invoice * Receipt is a terrible name for a table. And white spaces in column names is poor also.

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah ikr sorry. But wanted to clearly say that it is a link table that links the other two tables.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT i.invoice_no,
       r.receipt_no
FROM   invoice i
       FULL OUTER JOIN link l
       ON (i.invoice_no = l.invoice_no)
       FULL OUTER JOIN receipt r
       ON (r.receipt_no = l.receipt_no)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE invoice (Invoice_No) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE receipt (receipt_No) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE link (invoice_no, receipt_No) AS
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | INVOICE_NO | RECEIPT_NO |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2 | 1 |
> | *null* | 2 |
> | 1 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6aab830adde0096ba15864bbd5a28204)*

Answer (score 0):

This is called a full outer join.

One way to express it:

```
select * 
from invoice 
full outer join receipt 
     on (invoice_id, receipt_id) in (
         select invoice_id, receipt_id from invoice_receipt
     )
```